# Understanding a function. pcap and BPF

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, pcap

In my attempt at making a TCP program that can recieve acks and create connections I came across this function in an example program:

```
void *pth_capture_run(void *arg)
{
pcap_t *pd;
char *filter = "dst host 172.17.14.90 and ip";
char *dev = "fxp0";
char errbuf[PCAP_ERRBUF_SIZE];
bpf_u_int32 netp;
bpf_u_int32 maskp;
struct bpf_program  fprog;                  /* Filter Program   */
int dl = 0, dl_len = 0;

if ((pd = pcap_open_live(dev, 1514, 1, 500, errbuf)) == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot open device %s: %s\n", dev, errbuf);
    exit(1);
}

pcap_lookupnet(dev, &netp, &maskp, errbuf);
pcap_compile(pd, &fprog, filter, 0, netp);
if (pcap_setfilter(pd, &fprog) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot set pcap filter %s: %s\n", filter, errbuf);
    exit(1);
}
pcap_freecode(&fprog);
dl = pcap_datalink(pd);

switch(dl) {
    case 1:
        dl_len = 14;
        break;
    default:
        dl_len = 14;
        break;
}

if (pcap_loop(pd, -1, raw_packet_receiver, (u_char *)dl_len) < 0) {
    fprintf(stderr, "cannot get raw packet: %s\n", pcap_geterr(pd));
    exit(1);
}
}
```

Now I've gathered that this function opens a BPF device and sets the packet filter, then waits for the packet to arrive. However, being quite new to network programming I am unfamiliar with the various pcap functions and still a bit unclear as to what this function, in simple terms, does and how it does it. I've gone through this tutorial: http://yuba.stanford.edu/~casado/pcap/section1.html
but I'm still a bit confused. Can any of you explain it in simpler terms? Thanks!

Comment: What part exactly confuses you?

Comment: @RedX well most of it to be honest, but especially the first two if statements and the bit in between. I know i am a bit general here, but as I've said it's all new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have already figured out the function, at least logically, as for the first if statement, it attempts to open the device you're listening to and prints an error if it fails, the second one sets the pcap filter after it has been compiled.

If you want to know more about a specific function and its parameters, you should really just take a look at the man pages, e.g.

> man pcap_open_live